# Show that the largest eigenvalue of $A$ lies in the given interval

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Show that if the given matrix $A$ is positive semi-definite then the largest eigen value of $A$ lies in the interval $(6,7)$.

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 
5&1&1&1&1&1\\
1&2&1&0&0&0\\
1&1&2&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&1&0&0\\
1&0&0&0&1&0\\
1&0&0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$$

**My try**:

Since the matrix is given to be positive semidefinite so the spectral radius $\rho(A)$ must be an eigen value of $A$.

Also $\rho (A)=\max_{||x||=1}x^TAx$

I considered the vector $x=(1,0,0,0,0,0)$ then $\rho(A)\ge 5$

So I tried various $x$ such that $||x||=1$ but I find largest lower bound to be $5$.

Is there any way I can show that $\rho\ge 6$

Answer (score 1):

first things, it is positive definite, by [Sylvester's Law of Inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia#Statement_in_terms_of_eigenvalues)

> The law can also be stated as follows: two symmetric square matrices
>   of the same size have the same number of positive, negative and zero
>   eigenvalues if and only if they are congruent $ S ′ = A S A^T \; , \; $ with $A$ nonsingular

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 4 }{ 9 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 9 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 13 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 9 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 13 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 10 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 9 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 13 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 10 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 7 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 9 }{ 5 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 13 }{ 9 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 10 }{ 13 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 10 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 7 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 9 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 9 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 9 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 9 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 13 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 13 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 13 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 10 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 10 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
5 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Next, if $7I - H$ is also positive definite, but $6I - H$ indefinite, the largest eigenvalue lies between 6 and 7....

$$ Q_7^T D_7 Q_7 = 7I-H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 9 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 9 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 8 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 9 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 8 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 9 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 16 }{ 3 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 21 }{ 4 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 36 }{ 7 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 9 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 9 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 9 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 8 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
2 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 5 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$ Q_6^T D_6 Q_6 = 6I - H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  - 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  - 1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  - 1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 3 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 20 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 4 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: Can you kindly  explain why if $7I-H$ is positive definite and $6I-H$ is not,how $6\le \rho \le 7$?

Comment: How do you know that $7I-H$ is positive definite and $6I-H$  not

Answer (score 0):

There exist $2\times 2$ orthogonal matrix $Q_2$ and $3\times 3$ orthogonal matrix $Q_3$ such that
$$Q_2\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{2}\\0\end{bmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad Q_3\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{3}\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\,,$$
e.g. Householder reflections. Define $6\times6$ orthogonal block diagonal matrix $Q$ with $Q=\operatorname{diag}(1,Q_2,Q_3)$ and note that matrix $A$ is similar to the matrix
$$QAQ^T=\begin{bmatrix}5&\sqrt{2}&0&\sqrt{3}&0&0\\\sqrt{2}&3&0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0&0\\\sqrt{3}&0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\,.$$

Now we know that eigenvalues of $A$ different from $1$ must be eigenvalues of the matrix $B$ defined as
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}5&\sqrt{2}&\sqrt{3}\\\sqrt{2}&3&0\\\sqrt{3}&0&1\end{bmatrix}\,.$$
Also,
$\rho(A)=\max\{1,\rho(B)\}\,.$

Characteristic polynomial of matrix $B$ is
$$k(\lambda) = \lambda^3-9\lambda^2+18\lambda-4\,.$$
Its derivative is a quadratic polynomial whose zeros are $3\pm\sqrt{3}$. From here we conclude that $k'(\lambda)>0$ for $\lambda\in(3+\sqrt{3},+\infty)$. This means that $k(\lambda)$ is strictly increasing on that interval and has at most one zero in it.
Since $k(6)=-4<0$ and $k(7)=24>0$, we know that zero is actualy in $(6,7)$.
This shows that the largest eigenvalue of $B$, $\rho(B)$, satisfies $6<\rho(B)<7$, from where $6<\rho(A)<7$ follows.